# execution of instructions in a child process

Tags: python, fork

I want to exit from a child process when the execution of `os.system(comm)` will be done.

My code is:

```
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0: 
         #instruction
else:
         comm = "python file.py"
         os.system(comm)
         sys.exit("error")
```

Now, my file `file.py` contains a loop, and I can get out from it only if the condition is satisfied. But, even when the condition is not satisfied, the program exits from the loop and displays the message *`error`*.

Also it doesn't execute the rest of instructions in `file.py`.

`file.py` is :

```
while 1:
       if(condition):
           break
# rest of instructions
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg please pay attention to the code when formatting, indentation is meaningful in Python

Comment: @Kos I know, on the other hand I'd rather leave the code as formatted by the author just because of that, what if the OP have erroneous indentation? If I "fix" it the question may no longer be answerable.

Comment: my identations are done very well in my own code, I didn't pay attention here.

Comment: @nesskh so please edit and fix so that the code is readable, people already helped you with formatting quite a lot :) so the only thing left for you is code indentation

Comment: There's a thought, there is no such thing as `os.exit()` did you mean `os._exit()` or `sys.exit()`?

Comment: I am sorry I make a mistake I mean sys.exit("error")

Comment: Are you positive that it located `file.py`? Is the file in the PATH or in the same directory?

Comment: Yes I am sure that it enters and execute file.py it's in the same directory. And enven I put a message just after the loop and it was displayed

Comment: @ness kh Can you elaborate regarding the condition? Is it possible it behaves differently than you anticipated and the loop breaks due to valid reasons? Also, what does the parent process do while it waits?

Comment: No the condition is  not valid I am sure. Enven more, if it's valid as you have supposed why does my code move direclty to the error message and ignore the rest of instructions in file.py?

Comment: I am still waiting for any help pleaase!

Answer (score 0):

You should use os._exit(returncode)
Or better, instead of os.system use one of function os.exec (os.execvp or os.execvpe)

For more opportunities just use subprocess module.